# php preg_match characters

Tags: php, preg-match, character, special-characters

I need help with preg_match function in php. I have read a lot of answers on SO, but I can't get any needed information.

So, I would like that preg_match check for characters `a-z, A-Z, 0-9,` special characters `č, š, ž, đ, ć, Č, Š, Ž, Đ, Ć` and `! " # $ % & / ( ) = ? * ° ' + - * . , - _ ; :`

For first part `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9)` I saw how it is done, but for next part I don't have idea.

Comment: do you want only those special characters that you mentioned, or are those just examples ?

Comment: You just need a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) listing them all, and possibly the `/u` modifier. Where are you stuck? Show your test code.

Comment: [regex pal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%C4%8D%C5%A1%C5%BE%C4%91%C4%87%C4%8C%C5%A0%C5%BD%C4%90%C4%86!%22%23%24%25%26%2F()%3D%3F*%C2%B0'%2B*.%2C_%3B%5C-%5D%2B&input=e%20oiduaso%20diasu%20doia%20dasd0-asda).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply list all characters in a [character class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9čšžđćČŠŽĐĆ!"#$%&/()=?*°'+*.,_;:-]
```

Since the minus sign bears special semantics, I moved it to the end where it, well, [doesn't have special semantics](https://twitter.com/#!/RegexTip/status/187555606658433024). Make sure your editor encoding matches the input encoding (i.e. use UTF-8 everywhere).

By the way, that list is really excessive. You may want to simply use `\w`, [which stands for an arbitrary word character](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), or `\S` (anything but whitespace).

Comment: It works... what about space " ", can I also add it as other characters?

Comment: Sure, you can add any character in a character class. You'll just have to pay special attention to `]` and `-`.

Comment: Sure, why not. By the way, if this (or any other) answer solves your original question, feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).